# SSIS OLE DB Command data flow transformation SqlCommand size limit

Tags: sql, ssis, sqlcommand, oledbcommand

I'm running into a situation in a data flow where I think I'm reaching the size limit of the SqlCommand property of an OLE DB Command data flow transformation. Let me give you the set up:

I have a text file source containing a few columns. One of the columns is a string object with upwards of 50,000 characters. I wrote a stored procedure that accepts these columns, including the string object which gets parsed and added as several new rows in a SQL table. It works fine when the stored proc is called within SQL Server Management Studio and I can pass in large amounts of text (50k+).

Now in my data flow object in SSIS, I have an OLE DB Command transformation which calls the stored proc passing in the columns as parameters, including the string object (DT_NTEXT data type). If the text file column containing the string has less than 33,000 characters, the data flow works fine. Once it runs into a row in which the string column goes over the size of 32,767 characters, the data flow triggers a truncation error and that row is never processed.

The SQLCommand property only has 1 line which is the stored proc call:

```
EXEC usp_ParseDataColumns ?,?,?
```

The last parameter is the string object which can get very large. I'm assuming the transformation replaces each parameter with the row's data during run-time and if the property's value size exceeds 32,767 characters, it truncates and generates an error.

The error output that is generated by the OLE DB Command transformation is:

> The data value cannot be converted for reasons other than sign
>   mismatch or data overflow.

I tried searching for several alternatives, including using a variable, but not sure if that's the right path. I'm using an OLE DB Command because I need to perform other transformations afterwards on each row.

How can I resolve this or is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never encountered the OLEDB command being truncated, that's an odd one.  Please post the full error when you can.

As for a fix, I suggest re-architecting this data flow a little bit.  Break the work into logical pieces and stage the data multiple times.  So, for example,

- instead of using an OLEDB command, insert the data into a staging table.
- When the data flow task is complete, us an execute SQL task to either
  run that stored proc in a cursor, or better, execute a proc that will
  use the staged data as a source and perform a set based operation.
- Finally, use another execute SQL task or another data flow to finish
  the operation (whatever was happening after the OLEDB command)

I know this seems like more work to be inserting and reading data multiple times, but this technique performs invariably better than large complicated data flows with row-by-row operations.